# Why does the Yahoo Mail application for Android only show message snippets in search results?

Tags: yahoo-mail

When I do a search in the Yahoo Mail application and then open one of the search results, instead of seeing the entire message I only see a message snippet.

Is there a way to view the entire original email message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. It's ridiculous.

I don't really have a solution, but here's my workaround: I forward the found email to myself. (Doing this, you still won't be able to read the message in the composition window!!)

So you'll be able to read the forwarded message only when it comes around in your inbox.

I really do hope they'll fix this.